# Реализация уведомлений на QT

Tags: c++, qt

Помогите разобраться как можно реализовать механизм работы с уведомлениями через Qt. Механизм такой:

1. Появляется уведомление через анимацию. Если уведомление не единственное, то все остальные сдвигаются.
2. Уведомление висит и уходит(тоже через анимацию) спустя время, только если была сдвинута позиция мыши на момент появления.
3. Уведомление может уйти при нажатии кнопки закрытия на самом виджете уведомления.
4. Все остальные уведомления сдвигаются обратно, закрывая пустое место.

Я пытался реализовать подобное через машину состояний (QStateMachine), но есть несколько проблем:

а. если появляется несколько уведомлений одновременно, анимация прерывается на середине процесса. В обычном темпе все хорошо (Реализация updateGeometry или отслеживать сигнал finished у анимации не помогает);

б. неизвестно как грамотно добавить в машину состояние "сдвига"(см. 1 и 4) и переход в это состояние, если машина была уже запущена;

в. как должен быть эффективно реализован контроллер(менеджер) всего это стека.

Comment: Здесь показано более подробно: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Po4qdoqKJOs&feature=emb_logo&ab_channel=AlekseySidorov

Comment: без исходников чем вам помочь? разве что сочувствием